# How do you restrict a CiviContribute page using roles

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

I have a CiviContribute page which was intended to only be accessed by people renewing a specific type of membership.

We have found though, that it appears on a Google search and indeed a completely random person has signed up for the membership.

I have a Drupal Role for this membership type and also have a Group which we use as a mailing list; so would it be better to build it into a webform controlled by Access Control?

Comment: Webform might work but you would need to confirm if your Payment Processor is the type that works with webform-civi

Comment: I had that as a plan B as we already use that for an organisational relationship. I am surprised there is no option for a wholly renewal only option.

Comment: You might find this useful http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/4677/872

Answer (score 0):

Idea for a possible workaround:

- Create a group and role for the non-eligible users
- Set up a Drupal block that only shows on this page and only for this role
- put no visible content in the block, but create some JavaScript functionality to prevent non-eligible users to access the form