# Non-public contribution pages or event registrations (permissions)

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, permissions, registration, online-registration

With Webform-CiviCRM we can block access to a form unless the person is a known contact, such as a visitor following a customized link from CiviMail (or we could use other forms of permissions access).

Is there any way to do this for default contribution pages or event registrations? (e.g. creating a contribution/member signup page that is not publicly accessible?)

For example, if a certain membership is only meant to be accessible to a group after a vetting process of some kind, we may want to have a membership contribution form that is not generally accessible.

Comment: There are many solutions posted in this similar question here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/are-private-contribution-pages-a-thing