# Early Bird Registration by Membership Type

Tags: civievent, civimember

How can we give early access to registration forms to certain members, based on their membership status/role?

For instance,

Premium Members can access 2 weeks early and register.
Regular 1 weeks early.
Non-members on regular timing.

CiviCRM 4.7 / Drupal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take.

One is to use the [Group-Based Pricing](https://civicrm.org/extensions/group-based-pricing) extension with price sets to enable members-only price sets.

You could also use a custom extension - about 10 lines of code should get you there. See [Are private contribution pages a thing?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/4637/12)

Comment: I really enjoyed this comment. Thanks Jon. I was not aware of the Group-Based Pricing extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a third one: webform civicrm; combined with drupal member role sync and access permissions; no code required; Just check add one checkbox every week (who can submit webform);